# Print all not compatible versions in my Podfile and dependencies

Tags: cocoapods, dependency-management

I have a big project with a huge amount of dependencies. I have many not compatible dependencies. Now I fix this in that way.
I exec `pod install —repo-update` and look at error. There is one error in the message.
I'll fix problem and return to first step.
This can be replayed more than 10 times.
I think it is not good solution.
How can I print all list of not compatible versions pods in my pod file and dependencies.

Comment: I think it will stop at first incompatibility found. It won't list all incompatibilities, as it could be a nightmare and "false". Imagine having A(1.0.0) B(0.9.9), C(4.0.0), but A needs B(1.0.0)`, but C(4.0.0) works only with B(0.9.9), etc. Fixing one version incompatibility doesn't mean that one fix won't create later another incompatible version...